# Xcode, Objective-C Project: not compiling C++ file

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have C++ file header (`interface.hpp`) in my Objective-C project.

When I use it I get a compiler error on the line: `#include <map>`

```
map file not found
```

and it's the same for `#include <string>`

```
string file not found
```

It seems to me that, despite the file extension hpp, Xcode is compiling it as C header, rather than C++ header.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The language will depend on the suffix of the file from within which you `#include <interface.hpp>` - may be know the name/suffix of that file ?

Comment: Is your file included in .c or .m files, or only in .cpp and .mm?

Comment: @PaulR that's file is objective.C (.h) header

Comment: @Eiko Answered above: it's included in a objective-C header

Comment: @Patrick The real question is what implementation file includes this - as header files are compiled at all by themselves. You can only include cpp things in Objective-C++ files (.mm). Trying to include them in Objective-C (.m) will not work. No general advise here, but often renaming the .m files to .mm will solve the problem.

Comment: @Eiko I see, thanks. I've renamed the implementation file from .m to .mm, but I still get the same issue. Its header, is the one importing interface.hpp

Comment: Look at the error to see the file (and inclusion path) that gives the trouble.

Comment: @Eiko There was another path in the warning message: the file importing the header of the file importing the hpp file. So i've renamed that file to .mm too. Now, importing <map> and <string> is no longer a problem. However I get the same message on #import <mutex> and <iostream> that are few lines below. Why

Comment: @Eiko These are the one 2 paths in the warnings, still now. But they both have .mm extension.

Comment: @Eiko I meant #include <mutex> and <iostread>

Comment: It seems that what I need to do is open the project settings -> Build Settings and set C++ Language Dialect to C++11 and the C++ Standard Library to libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support). I'm still facing other compile errors, but that one seems solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension of the header is irrelevant.  What is important is the extension of the file that includes that header.  If you want to include a C++ header in Objective-C code, you need to change the extension of the Objective-C file to `.mm`.  This indicates that the file is an Objective-C++ source file (a different language, in fact, so be careful that you know what you're doing).  Headers that are included in a `.mm` file will be parsed as Objective-C++, and so then your C++ constructs should work.

Comment: What if the file that includes the header is an Objective-C header? (.h)

Comment: Again, irrelevant.  The important thing is the actual source file (.m, .mm, .c, .cpp, whatever) that ultimately does the include.  The extension of the actual source file determines the language in which all included headers will be parsed.

Comment: Ok I see. However. I've renamed the source file to ".mm" and I still get the same compile error. I've restarted xCode, cleaned and rebuilt. Its header contains the line importing the interface.hpp file.

Comment: Since the additional errors that you were getting with <mutex> and <iostream> were unrelated to your original question, it seems to me that my answer correctly answered your question.  It would be nice to have this answer accepted.

Comment: @bhaller - Your answer is the correct "Text Book" answer. I just started getting the exact same problem, it only surfaced after I upgraded my xcode from 7.3 to 8. (compiled under 7.3 no problem) None of the code changed, but all of a sudden, xcode stopped recognizing my C++ files. I can compile them from the command line, if I invoke the objective-c++ compiler, but running through xcode is a non-starter.  I've tried all the different llvm & language dialect options. I could only get it use the C++ compiler if I changed the "Compile Sources As" option to C++ but then I get other linking errors.

Comment: This just saved me after hours of frustration, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the file extension to `.mm` in order to use it.

Comment: It's not an implementation file, it's a header

Comment: Xcode can know .m and .mm file, the cpp file had been compile to target file.so if you want use it, you can make contain file extension to.mm. I sorry my English low ,can't answer beautiful

Answer (score 0):

If changing the extension to .mm is not working try adding **-l"c++"** to Other Linker Flags in build settings.

Comment: also add -ObjC to other linker flag